# Intermediate value theorem proof using this structure

Tags: real-analysis

This is the specific theorem to prove: If $f$ is a continuous function whose domain includes a closed interval $[a,b]$, and $L$ is a horizontal line, and $(a,f(a))$ is below $L$, and $(b,f(b))$ is above $L$, then there is a number $x$ between $a$ and $b$ such that $(x,f(x))$ is on $L$.

Proof: $f(a)<x<f(b)$ or $f(a)>x>f(b)$
Lets consider $\epsilon > 0$, then there exists a $\delta > 0$,
such that $|f(x)-f(c)| < \epsilon$ for every $|x-c| < \delta$,
so $f(x) - \epsilon < f(c) < f(x) + \epsilon$,
for each $x$ within $c - \delta$ and $c + \delta$
there is an $x$ between $c$ and $c- \delta$,
so $f(c) < f(x) + \epsilon < L + \epsilon$,
Also values of $x$ between $c$ and $c + \delta$ not contained gives
$f(c) > f(x) - \epsilon > L - \epsilon$,
combining both inequalities gives
$L - \epsilon < f(c) < L + \epsilon$,
this gives $f(a) < L < f(b)$
similarly for $f(a) > L > f(b)$
Therefore there is a number $x$ between a and b such that $(x,f(x))$ is on $L$.

I know the proof is nearly correct. I know that I may have used the wrong variables in certain spots. If anyone has any insight on fixing this proof from the minor errors but not changing the structure of the proof. I know there are many ways to prove this theorem but I need to do it this way.

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your math. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: To be frank your proof is no proof at all. You are not really sure what you are doing here. In particular your proof does not indicate what $x, c, L$ represent. You seriously need to reconsider your approach. You can begin by saying "Let $y=k$ be the equation of the horizontal line $L$ then $k$ lies between $f(a) $ and $f(b) $ and we need to find an $x\in(a, b) $ such that $f(x) =k$. "

Comment: For more details see this [blog post](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/06/continuous-functions-on-closed-interval-intermediate-value-theorem.html).

Comment: Domain and range please, I'm assuming $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. I also cannot understand this proof at all.