# Arbitrary function on a horizontal line L between two points

Tags: real-analysis

Problem: If $f$ is a continuous function whose domain includes a closed
interval $[a,b]$, and $L$ is a horizontal line, and $(a,f(a))$ is below $L$, and $(b,f(b))$ is above $L$, then there is a number $x$ between $a$ and $b$ such that $(x,f(x))$ is on $L.$

Proof:

Let $f$ be a continuous function whose domain includes a closed
interval $[a,b]$

Let $L$ be a horizontal line

Let $(a,f(a))$ be below $L$

Let $(b,f(b))$ be above $L$,

Then by the definition of continuity, if $S$ is any open interval containing the number $f(x)$, then there is an open interval $T$ containing the number $x$ such that if %t% $\in$ $T$, and   $t$ is in
the domain of $f$, then $f(t)$ $\in$ $S$.

So on this problem, this is basically introducing the definition of deriviation correct? Basically I'm just looking for a "$t$" $\in$ $T$ that maps to $f(t)$ $\in$ $S$ that is between $(a, f(a))$ and $(b, f(b))$ on the line $L$?

Comment: You did ask a very similar question quite recently, in which the parameters were slightly different. In the answer, I discussed in detail the proof. I showed you how to get the "t" in that case. You can modify the proof for that answer, to this one. Also, this question does not require any kind of "'derivation"(I think you mean derivative), it is a simple rewrite of the previous answer.

Comment: Same question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2546922/72031

Answer (score 0):

Call the horizontal line in the plane as the equation $y=c$, so essentially the question says that $f(a)<c<f(b)$, then Intermediate Value Theorem says that there is some $x\in(a,b)$ such that $c=f(x)$. So $(x,f(x))=(x,c)$ satisfies the equation $y=c$.